# Can you keep track of wallet address that trade your token on exchanges in smart contract?

Tags: ether, contract-design, erc-20, ico

Can you keep track of wallet address that trade your token on exchanges in smart contract after crowd sale ends? For example, I have token called OLG, it has been 100 days since ICO ends and many people trade OLG on Bittrex. A lot of them have OLG at the moment, even though some of them didn't participate in ICO.

Can I know their wallet address in my smart contract?

Comment: have you found a solution for this yet?

Comment: yes, what i did was i added a map<walletAddress,tokenPurchased> whenever there is a purchase happen during ICO or simply when someone call send() function to send his token to someone else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the token’s contract on https://etherscan.io/ and see all of the transactions in that token.

Comment: it is a good idea, my question was not well organized, I actually was developing ICO smart contract that has dividend functionality. Of course you can just look at etherscan if you dont need everything functioning in smart contract